# Touch events in a UICustomview is not working - UICustomview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, uistackview

- i created a custom view

  - i had an another view in a viewcontroller which is stackview act as a parent view for customview.
  - when i displaying view dynamically to that stackview(parent view). view is appearing but Button touch events are not recognizing.
  - when i displaying customview in a superview - button events are working.

i checked all views userinteraction enable is true.

i dont have any idea whats going on. 
any solution

Comment: Is the button first responder? Is there another view above it

Comment: in customview i placed multiple labels and submit button that’s it. no other views above custom view

Comment: problem is when i’m arranging it  as a sub view to parent view. button is not responding to touch events

Comment: I helped with a similar sounding issue earlier - check the answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126701/swift-uistackview-of-uicontrols-with-selector-method-that-doesnt-fire/53134025#53134025 - it may be that the constraints of your stackview are causing it to have an ambiguous layout.

Comment: okay i will refer it

Comment: Isn't it clipped? Try view debugger.